# $p^*H$ for a blow-up of $\mathbb P^n$ in a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $p: S \to \mathbb P^n$ be a blow-up in a point $x$, and $p^*: Pic(\mathbb P^n) \to Pic(S)$ be a inverse image on linear bundles, or, equally, on divisors modulo rational equivalence. Then it seems that $p^*H = \tilde H$, where $\tilde H$ is the strict transform of some hyperplane which does not contain $x$, because one can consider a section $s \in \Gamma(\mathbb P^n, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(H))$ which does not vanish in $x$, then its preimage $s^* \in \Gamma(S, \mathcal O_S(p^*(H)))$ does not vanish along the exceptional divisor $E$, only along some hyperplane $\tilde H$. From the other side, Beauville proves that $p^*H = \tilde H + E$ if $H$ passes one time through $x$. Where am I wrong and what is $p^*H \in Pic(S)=\mathbb Z\tilde H \oplus \mathbb ZE$?

Comment: You have changed your original question  which was about blowing up $\mathbb P^2$, not  blowing up $\mathbb P^n$. This  is a bad idea: if you can't solve a simple problem there is no reason to ask about generalizations. Anyway  you should think **carefully** about what you want **before** you post  a question. In the present case you are confusing readers (which is not good etiquette)  because my answer to the former version of the question no longer matches your unfortunate modification.

Comment: Georges: I reacted on your comment "hyperplanes in $\mathbb P^2$ are called lines", and don't see why this generalisation should completely change the problem as $\mathbb P^2$ is just an example of my misunderstanding. Feel free to answer any version you like, but please  stop pursuing me by commenting on it in other places.

Answer (score 3):

**Compute, don't think!**

Consider the line $H: v-7u=0$ through the origin $O=(0:0:1)$ in $\mathbb P^2_{u:v:w}$.
  What is its pull-back in $S$ under $p$ ?
In one  chart $U \subset S$ of $S$ with coordinates $x,y$ the morphism $p$ is given by $(x,y)\mapsto (u=x:v=xy: w=1)$
The inverse image of the divisor $H$ is thus the divisor $D: xy-7x=0$ in $U$, which is the union of the divisors  $D_1: x=0$ and $D_2 : y-7=0$
Taking the closure in $S$ we obtain $p^{-1}(H)=\bar D_1 + \bar D_2 \in \operatorname {Div}(S)$ and thus taking divisor classes $$p^{*}(H)=E + \tilde H \in \operatorname {Pic}(S)$$ where  $\tilde H$ is the class of the strict transform $\bar D_2 $ of $H$ (or equivalently $\tilde H$ is the class of the inverse image $p^{-1}(L)\subset S$ of any line $L\subset \mathbb P^2$ not passing through $O$).

Comment: My answer is to the original question, which was about blowing up $ \mathbb P^2$, not $\mathbb P^n$. It is quite frustrating to take the time to post a detailed answer and have this work spoiled by the OP's unfortunate decision to change the question.